# CGEL's argument on the constituent structure of certain sentences that involve 'as well as'

Tags: syntax, english, constituents

In [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) on pp. 1316-1317, we find a discussion of two different uses of *as well as*:

> [70] i b. *[Abstraction] [as well as impressionism] **were** Russian
>   inventions.*  
>        ii a. *[Beauty]
>   [as well as love] **is** redemptive.*

(The emphasis in boldface is mine.) The analysis goes like this:

> In [i] *as well as* behaves like the coordinator *and*. ...In [ib] the
>   form 
>   *were* indicates that the subject NP is plural, just like *abstraction and impressionism*. ...
>
> In [70ii], by contrast, *as well as* behaves markedly differently from
>   a coordinator. In  [iia] the 3rd person singular verb-form *is*
>   indicates that this time the subject is singular: *is* agrees with
>   *beauty*, so that *as well as love* is treated syntactically as an adjunct, not a coordinate. ...
>
> We must conclude that idiomatic *as well as* can be construed
>   syntactically in two  ways, introducing an element that is either
>   coordinate (as in [70i]) or subordinate (as in [ii]). In the former
>   case, we take it to have been reanalysed as a compound coordinator. In
>   the latter case there has been no such syntactic reanalysis, and here
>   *as well as* does not form a constituent. This is evident from the fact that *as well* can occur  on its own: compare *Beauty is
>   redemptive and love is as well*. In [iia], then, the second *as* is a
>   preposition taking the NP *love* as its complement, and the whole PP
>   *as love* is an indirect complement in the AdvP *as well as love*.

My question concerns how this argument makes use of the sentence

[B] *Beauty is redemptive and love is as well.*

This seems to be a nontrivial rewriting of [70iia]. What justification do we have for the claim that the *as well* in [70iia] and the one in [B] are 'the same' *as well*?

The 'data' show just this: that the idiomatic *as well as* seems to function in at least two different ways, and the way it functions in [70iia] is one in which it is not equivalent to a coordinator.  CGEL says that the difference between the occurrences of *as well as* in [70ib] and [70iia] is that *as well as* is a constituent in [70ib] but not in [70iia]. And CGEL's evidence for this assertion is that *as well* appears alone in [B]. Thus, CGEL's argument **assumes**, rather than **proves**, that the *as well* in [70ib] is the same as the one in [B]. So: how do we know that this assumption of CGEL's is true?

To repeat, all we know is that the *as well* in [70ib] is not like the *as well* in [70iia]; but why does this imply that therefore the *as well* in [70ib] must be like the *as well* in [B]?

Comment: why is the link from SO ads? http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468

Comment: @adel-rahimi See the first answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30392/regarding-rads-stackoverflow-com).

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the argument based on [B] is bogus.

I have my doubts that *Beauty as well as love is redemptive* really has a subordinate construction.  Suppose we elaborate the example, *Beauty of form as well as love of form is redemptive* and see what happens when we try to extract *form*.

```
What do we seek the beauty of as well as the love of?
```

Not too bad, huh?  And since the prepositional object gets extracted from both constituents connected by *as well as*, this suggests that the construction is coordinate, rather than subordinate.

There is a very interesting discussion of all this in McCawley's **The Syntactic Phenomena of English** starting on page 298.  At least some of that is on line [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA309&lpg=PA309&dq=McCawley%20phenomena%20%22as%20well%20as%22&source=bl&ots=uOiv6J6vOg&sig=2q2fdcLyxrm647F5tzyAmLLn66Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ6ZeepofMAhWFKCYKHRB4D_0Q6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=McCawley%20phenomena%20%22as%20well%20as%22&f=false).

Comment: Very interesting, as always. Let  [W] stand for your _What do we seek..._ sentence; let [E] stand for your 'elaborated' sentence; finally, let [E'] stand for  _Beauty of form as well as love of form **are** redemptive._ Now, how do we know that [W] concerns [E] rather than [E']? In other words, isn't it the case that the test you propose is insensitive to precisely the distinction with which the whole trouble started, namely, whether the verb should be singular or plural?

Comment: You're right that I haven't proved anything.  I was proceeding on the assumption that the contrast in [70] has something to do with the difference between the sorts of the nouns "abstraction" and "impressionism" versus the more concrete "beauty" and "love".  However, I realize that is quite vague.

Comment: More to the point, surely _as well as_ can appear in sentences like [70ib] where the coordinates are perfectly concrete. An example: _Yettaw as well as Rambo seem unable to resist being in the presence of saintly women held against their wills_ ([source](https://goo.gl/iVAAAR)).

Comment: I guess you and *CGEL* are assuming that a singular-agreeing *as well as* is not coordinate?  Why do you think that?

Comment: No, no... well, CGEL clearly does. I don't know what to think, thus this question of mine. The reason I made the preceding comment is that you had said that 'the contrast in [70] has something to do with the difference between the sorts of the nouns "abstraction" and "impressionism" versus the more concrete "beauty" and "love".' The point I was trying to make is that the levels of abstraction have nothing to do with that contrast in [70], since the same contrast can be illustrated through examples where the analogs of _abstraction, impressionism, beauty,_ and _love_ are all concrete concepts.

Comment: CGEL's reason, as far as I understand it, is this: a distinguishing property of coordination is that the coordinates are of equal status, so 'the functions of head and dependent are not applicable' (p. 1276). But the singular verb in [70iia] strongly suggests that _beauty_ is the head (the suggestion becomes very strong if what follows _as well as_ is a plural expression, e.g. [J]  _John as well as the others thinks that..._). Thus, in [70iia] and [J], the _as well as_ introduces not a coordinate, but a subordinate element.

Comment: I suppose this discussion is partly about semantics, i.e. about what one should even mean by the term 'coordination' (the sentences [70iia] and [J] representing tricky borderline cases).

Comment: But McCawley points out that coordinated constituents mostly do not take plural agreement (*or*, *but*).  *And* is exceptional.  (I get the impression that the authors of CGEL never got around to reading McCawley -- that was a mistake.)

Comment: I see... though one would think that if _as well as_ is at all like a coordinator, it would be more like _and_ rather than _but_ or _or_. About McCawly, it would have been ironic if they really didn't read him, seeing how he served on the Board of Consultants for the project (but, of course, died before it got completed).

Comment: I don't claim to understand the contrast of [70], but if I were to attempt an analysis, I would begin with the conjecture that "as well as ..." in the second fails to affect verb agreement not because it is subordinate, but because it is parenthetical, and not actually in the same clause as "is".  The example could better have been written "Beauty, as well as truth, is redemptive".  McCawley proposes a theory of such constructions.

Comment: I guess the question becomes, Is there a reason to prefer one analysis over another? CGEL's argument using [B] may be invalid, but their conclusion may still be correct. As far as I am able to follow, so far, both the subordination analysis and the parenthetical analysis seem viable.

Comment: I don't know. -

Comment: OK. Thank you so much! You have, as always, been extremely informative and helpful.

Comment: Your example might be problematic: there is no reason to assume that your example is not an instance of CaGEL's coordination *as well as*.

Comment: @Araucaria, since I gave my example to support the theory that *as well as* is coordinate, I find your comment problematic.

Comment: @GregLee I'm being characteristically unclear. What I meant is just that CaGEL would agree that the *as well as* in your example was a coordinator. It isn't one of those cases where they'd analyse it as the head of an adjunct.

Comment: @Araucaria, my example assumed that "truth as well as beauty" in the example was enough like the second example of [70] to show that the example in [70] was a coordination, in contradiction to what CaGEL says.  What you're saying now is that, after all, my example is not enough like that original example, which vitiates my argument.  Have I understood you?  If so, yes, I understand that criticism, which was also made by linguisticturn earlier in this discussion.

Comment: @GregLee Yes, that's what I was aiming at.